# Dataflow job keeps showing "starting"

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I created a pipeline with Python flex template, and created a Dataflow job from that template.

The job started, and showing "Runnning". There're several steps in the pipeline, and 2 of them are showing "Starting" for almost 40 minutes. All other steps are showing "Running".

There's no log file or anything I can use to check for what's happening.

How can I know what caused this?

---

**update**

I managed to find the error log, thanks to @seaver-olson

[image]

Just add this log file.

Comment: can i see the code that is malfunctioning

Comment: The thing is, I don't know which part of the code is causing problem. In fact, it works well and fast on my local environment. Anyway, please my updated question.

Comment: usually when something happens there is a error in logs. Do you see it? Maybe it is at the job level on that specific step.

Comment: start in debug mode with ``--defaultWorkerLogLevel=DEBUG`` flag

Comment: @lonut there's even no log for the "Starting" steps... For the whole job, the log file exists, but the only error is when I stopped the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason some are able to start is because they do not require workers.  you need to click the link to `Stackdriver` in the job logs and then add `worker-startup` in the logs drop down in order to see any of those errors.